# Dagger-Hilt: @ViewModelInject is not injecting MyViewModel and crash?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

In exploring the ViewModelInject of Dagger-Hilt, I follow the example in https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodels

I try to inject the ViewModel into my activity as follow

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.hilt.Assisted
import androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelInject
import androidx.lifecycle.*
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication: Application()

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    private val textDataObserver =
        Observer<String> { data -> text_view.text = data }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewModel.showTextDataNotifier.observe(this, textDataObserver)
        btn_fetch.setOnClickListener { viewModel.fetchValue() }
    }
}

class MyViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @Assisted val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    val repository: Repository
) :
    ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {

    private val showTextLiveData
            = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("DefaultKey")

    val showTextDataNotifier: LiveData<String>
        get() = showTextLiveData

    fun fetchValue() {
        showTextLiveData.value = repository.getMessage()
    }
}


@Singleton
class Repository @Inject constructor() {
    fun getMessage() = "From Repository"
}
```

It crash complaining

```
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.elyeproj.simplehilt.MyViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.hilt.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:69)
```

I try manually creating the ViewModel using the view model factory (the non-injection approach), it works fine.

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.hilt.Assisted
import androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelInject
import androidx.lifecycle.*
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication: Application()

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels{
        MyViewModelFactory(this, Repository(), intent.extras)
    }

    private val textDataObserver =
        Observer<String> { data -> text_view.text = data }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        viewModel.showTextDataNotifier.observe(this, textDataObserver)
        btn_fetch.setOnClickListener { viewModel.fetchValue() }
    }
}

class MyViewModelFactory(
    owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    private val repository: Repository,
    defaultArgs: Bundle? = null
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, handle: SavedStateHandle
    ): T {
        return MyViewModel(
            handle,
            repository
        ) as T
    }
}

class MyViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @Assisted val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    val repository: Repository
) :
    ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {

    private val showTextLiveData
            = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("DefaultKey")

    val showTextDataNotifier: LiveData<String>
        get() = showTextLiveData

    fun fetchValue() {
        showTextLiveData.value = repository.getMessage()
    }
}

@Singleton
class Repository @Inject constructor() {
    fun getMessage() = "From Repository"
}
```

Did I do anything wrong in the use of `@ViewModelInject`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create instance of viewmodel after using Hilt in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471849/cannot-create-instance-of-viewmodel-after-using-hilt-in-android)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Apparently I miss out adding a kapt, which is `kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'`

The list of dependencies in my `build.gradle` is as below

```
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha'
```

Just for completeness, the plugin is below

```
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: My Problem was, I was using viewmodel in Fragment and on Fragment i didn't mention @AndroidEntryPoint. I mentioned that on Activity but not on Fragment.

Comment: You saved my day! I was missing implementation for "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0"

Comment: I haved the same error. In my case, I was missing **`implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0"`** and **`implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"`**. When I added that into `app/build.gradle` the problem was solved.

Answer (score 53):

`@ViewModelInject` is deprecated in the newer `hilt` version

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/hilt/lifecycle/ViewModelInject

Use `HiltViewModel`

```
@HiltViewModel
class TasksViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val taskRepository: TaskRepository
) : ViewModel() {

}
```

Comment: I tried using this while doing the Android Testing course but I'm still getting this error:                                                                                  InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.tasks.TasksViewModel> has no zero argument constructor

Comment: If anyone like @AndrewChelix getting an issue even after adding the above answer then makes sure all hilt dependencies should be updated also.

Comment: ...and {Remove the old androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel dependency from your build.gradle file} from here - https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.34

Answer (score 14):

For **Jetpack Compose lovers** if `hiltViewModel()` is not being resolved, just ensure you have these 3 dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.42"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
```

Of course, remember to apply the plugins.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i am getting error from last day

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add that If you are on a multi-module project, you have to have `kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'` on the `:app` module as well for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

For me all the dependencies were perfectly placed but missed out on inheriting the ViewModel class (androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel)

***ViewModel()***

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(): ViewModel()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to search for your ViewModel's generated java files like below via Find in Path (⇧⌘F or Ctrl+Shift+F).
[image]
If there are no auto-generated java files. It means you forgot to add this dependency to your module's gradle file which generates necessary java files for every **@HiltViewModel** annotation.

`kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$version"`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following dependencies are in your `app/build.gradle`:

```kotlin
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"

    // Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.33-beta'

    // Hilt ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.7'
```

into your build.gradle file