# Dagger Hilt deprecated @ViewModelInject to @HiltViewModel migration issue

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

recently I migrate the `ViewModelInject` in dagger hilt to `@HiltViewModel` by I am getting the error like this.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class io.chativo.chat.viewmodel.TicketViewModel

Original Code

```
class TicketViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val ticketRepository: TicketRepository
): ViewModel() {
.....
}
```

Updated code

```
@HiltViewModel
class TicketViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val ticketRepository: TicketRepository
): ViewModel() {
```

The original code works perfectly, but after I migrate to `@HiltViewModel`, I keep getting the `Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel` error. Any idea why this happen?

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

// dagger - hilt (dependency injection)
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31-alpha'
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.29.1-alpha"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.29.1-alpha'
```

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471849/cannot-create-instance-of-viewmodel-after-using-hilt-in-android

Comment: here is my dependency 
```implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31.2-alpha'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.29.1-alpha"
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha03'```. All already updated to latest. but why still getting error?

Comment: ensure your `activity/fragment` is having `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation

Comment: @AndroidEntryPoint have you added this for the activity / fragmnet ?

Comment: try this : iamkdblue 's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998051/cannot-create-an-instance-of-class-viewmodel

Comment: you are missing `implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01'` this library

Comment: @UsamaAtlaf yes, all of the acitivty/fragment having `@AndroidEntryPoint` or else the original code wont work. 
and also I did apply these dependencies.

I edited my question with dependencies to make it clear

Comment: I think the latest version is 2.33-beta (for the `com.google.dagger.*`) This includes `hilt-android:` and `hilt-compiler:` (but not the classpath plug-in which is still `2.32-alpha`). This may not solve the issue, but you should try to use the same "versions" where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I get the correct solution by myself. The compiler version should be the same with its library version.

```
// dagger - hilt (dependency injection)
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31-alpha'
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.31.1-alpha"
```

Hope this helps someone who struggle for an answer.